# What does it take to be an Astrodynamics Engineer?

Tags: engineering, astrodynamics, space-industry, career

Astrodynamics is really complicated and requires some incredible intuition for not just physics, but math and programming.

Most job descriptions for Astrodynamics Engineer say something about a degree (bachelor's or master's) in a STEM related field.

I think that someone with the skills and enthusiasm would get the job regardless of bachelor's or master's or Ph.D.?

If you just have a physics bachelor's degree what chances do you stand of getting the "job"? How much know-how would you need to demonstrate to get in with a bachelor's?

Comment: Is your question really "what does it take to get hired as an Astrodynamics Engineer"? As a former manager who hired people in a Large Aerospace Firm (LAF), I can tell you the hiring process, at least at LAFs, is extremely bureaucratic. If the job req says "engineering degree" and you don't have one, your application will be round-filed immediately.  However, the people who wrote the job reqs (like me) understand how to work the system and if it were appropriate, would list several degrees.

Comment: Both groups that I hired for were open to hiring physics majors as well as engineers (they were not Astrodynamics positions though which is why I'm commenting instead of answering). In my experience the single most important thing you can do as a new grad to get hired is have some engineering experience on your resume. Intern, or get a student engineer job in the summer, etc. Co-oping is the best. This shows that you are actually employable in a technical position and is immensely valuable to the person evaluating you.

Comment: As a counterpoint to @OrganicMarble, I also interview and recommend (**or not**) potential candidates, but for a Small Aerospace Firm. Most of the time, I work in various aspects of astrodynamics, simulation, and GN&C flight software. Employers did not require an advanced degree 20 years ago. Requiring an advanced degree is more or less standard now. You might be able to break into this field if you have "just" a bachelors degree in a relevant field, plus four years of experience. That's a Catch 22. How do you get that four years of experience if you can't get "the job" in the first place?

Comment: Different organizations in different countries have different requirements. Some organizations very biased toward hiring PhDs with published papers. Others hire fresh-outs with a bachelors degree. Country also matters since orbital mechanics is without a doubt a dual use technology. I don't think there can be a definitive answer to this question. Questions at this site ideally should have definitive answer, which is why I am going to vote to close. I'm not saying this is a bad question; it is a good question. It's just not a good question for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a definitive answer to this question does not and cannot exist.